# Android 2.2 security in 2016

Tags: security, 2.2-froyo

I have an old Samsung Dart t499 that I would like to give to my son for simple texting and phone calls.

Assuming that (1) we don't install any apps and just use the ones that came by default on the device; (2) we turn off MMS autoretrieval; (3) we don't browse the web, open sms or respond to sms messages from unknown people and (4) we use a Google account created just for this device and not linked to any other information or accounts that we have.

Are there any security concerns/risks that we need to be aware of?

Comment: Unless you plan to use the Google account for location, why specifically you need an Android phone for?

Comment: It is much easier to text by using voice recognition than it is to type.  Plus the phone has a decent camera compared to a feature phone.  Plus we already own the phone and it seems a shame not to use it for something.